# My posts section for logged in user

Tags: posts, permalinks, users, archives, links

I would like to create a page that shows only posts written by the user logged in and get a link (such as www.example.com/AuthorPostsID) to put on the menu. I'm trying for two days. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

EDIT: 
I tried using the following code, putting it in the function.php file, but I do not know how to proceed:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):    
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>       
    <?php           
    endwhile;    
else :    
    echo "not logged in";    
endif;
```

Comment: Since you have been trying for two days, certainly there is code you can post even if that code doesn't work.

Comment: You added a comment that had some code in it, and then deleted the comment. (It saw it just before you deleted). [Edit] that code into the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I deleted the code because it was bad formatted as comment

Comment: Yes, formatting in comments is very minimal. You should always edit important information into the question or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put your code in your theme functions. This needs to be a custom page template. Learn about page templates here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Your code is custom loop so you need to also learn about loops and then using WP_Query so next stop will be here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Then read this page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

After you do this you will be ready to implement your custom loop to show authors their posts.

Study, the codex so that you have a better understanding of how WordPress works before you make changes to things that will break WordPress.

Then when you ask questions here you will be able to get a better answer to problems that you are having because the people here will understand your question better.